# Barra de pesquisa VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

como eu poso fazer uma barra de pesquisa que caso não encontre o valor no banco, retorne uma mensagem dizendo que não foi encontrado no banco ? Eu não sei imprimir essa mensagem.

Answer (score 1):

Basta você criar uma variável vazia que, ao não cumprir a regra desejada, preencha a mesma com o texto que preferir. Para exibi-la é preciso fazer a [interpolação](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#text-interpolation), basta colocar a variável entre dois blocos de chaves.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="searchText" type="text">
    <button @click="search">Pesquisar</button>
    <p>{{ error }}</p> <!-- Exibe o valor da variável -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        searchText: '',
        error: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      search() {
        this.error = '' // Limpa o campo de erro

        if (!this.searchText) {
          this.error = 'O campo está vazio'
        }
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ah sim, entendi valeu.